# WordPress Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, map

Does anyone know of a nice map plugin for WordPress? I have a diary website in WordPress where each diary entry has the latitude and longitude of where each post was written. I thought it would be cool for each post to have a google map showing where each entry was written.

Maybe even show the path that was taken while writing the diary.

Any ideas?

Comment: found anything that worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-map-shortcode/) and [two](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comprehensive-google-map-plugin/) really interesting ones at the general plugin database.

Slightly different with their layout options, but they both take data input (coordinates and what-have-you) in plenty of formats.

hope that helps,

J